# Not able to generate SQL Join query for Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table structure like this and I am using Postgres

`ContactPhoneRelation`

| id | ContactId | PhoneId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 999 |
| 2 | 123 | 998 |

I have another table `GroupTable`

| id | groupId | ContactId | PhoneId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 | 999 |
| 2 | 2 | 123 | 999 |
| 3 | 2 | 123 | 998 |

I am trying to fetch the data from `ContactPhoneRelation` which does not exist in `groupId` `1` and `ContactId` is `123`, So I want to query such that where `groupId` is `1` and `ContactId` is `123` and `ContactId` `phoneId` both does not exists in `groupId` `1`

So in return, it should give me this result

| id | contactId | PhoneId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 123 | 998 |

If I query for `groupId` `2`, It should give me 0 rows in return.

I tried this query but it gave me the opposite data.

```
select * from ContactPhoneRelation cp
left join GroupTable gt on gt.ContactId  = cp.ContactId
where cp.contactId = '123' and gt.groupId = 1
```

Comment: You can use !=, like `gt.groupId != 1`.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I don't understand what you are trying to achive. But maybe this is because of language issues.

For better understanding I added an example on db<>fiddle: [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=da899655956f7e07192a9d3c27dd94d9)

Edit (29.09.2021; 16:49):

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        b.groupID
        ,a.ContactID
        ,a.PhoneID
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            ContactId
            ,PhoneID
        FROM
            ContactPhoneRelation
        ) a
        FULL JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            groupID
        FROM
            GroupTable
        ) b ON (1=1)
     ORDER BY groupID, ContactID, phoneID
     ) c
     LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupTable d ON (
         c.groupID = d.groupID
         AND c.ContactID = d.ContactID
         AND c.PhoneID = d.PhoneID
     )
WHERE
    d.groupID IS NULL
```

Comment: You see that the group table contains the contact table data, Group Id 2 contains the contact id 123's both phone ids but group1 contains only the 1 data.

So I have a task to insert the data to group 1, but only those which does not exists already in group 1. 

So group 1 already have contact id 123's phone Id 999 but it does not have 123's phone id 998. So I want to query the data which is not in the group table

Comment: This query `select * from ContactPhoneRelation cp
left join GroupTable gt on gt.ContactId  = cp.ContactId and gt.PhoneId  = cp.PhoneId
where cp.contactId = '123' and gt.groupId = 1` gives data which exists in group table, I want which does not exists in group table

Comment: I edited my first answer. I hope, that helps. I edited the db<>fiddle to: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=21dccb207ff37223052608e9677f375d